# Why is my RF switch catching on fire?

Tags: short-circuit, inductance, ringing

The pictured circuit below works nicely as a electronically switchable-gain photodiode amplifier.

Except for the small issue that as it is being plugged in, U2, a fast CMOS RF switch, has  a nonzero chance of catching on fire.

[image]

Here's a partial view of the PCB:

[image]

From what I can tell of the wreckage, the +15V and -15V supplies get shorted to ground through the RF switch, U2, ADG1219. They are >1A capable off-board linear supplies, so they burn through the tiny RF switch.

Now, I realize I need fuses.

But what's causing the destruction of the switch? It seems to me EN and V+, being jumped, means the chip won't exceed its absolute maximum ratings for the digital inputs (Vdd+0.3).

I can reliably produce an RF-switch-molotov-cocktail after about 10 or so plugs- and re-plugs of the power connector. So it has something to do with the rise of the supplies, but I don't see what I can do about this?

Any ideas???

Comment: Perhaps a carefully sized PTC resetable fuse(s) would help. P.S. I appreciate fir sense of humor. :-)

Comment: "... after about 10 or so plugs- and re-plugs of the power connector" - are you hot-plugging the circuit?  If so, watch the +/-15V rails with a scope during the "plug in" - you may have overshoot due to inductance of the wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding 620 ohm series resistors on my +/-15V traces going to the chip (power and enable pins) and that fixed it. The device draws next to no bias current.

My thought process was inrush current causing a burnout of the internal protection diodes, leading to shorting.

So, with the absolute maximum digital current of 30mA in mind, I chose 620R, because 15V/620R <30mA, and wasn't large enough to cause huge RC time constants which could add its own issues. This prevented further killing of switches.

In retrospect, Im not sure if the problem was inrush current -  Selvek was right in his comment on voltage overshoots, as my cable is over 10 feet! Lots of inductance in such a cable; energy is stored in the magnetic field, which gets released when plugged in - causing a large transient voltage overshoot at the sensitive switch. Adding series resistance just damped this overshoot to acceptable levels.